# Why are we using the interaction picture?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, interactions, time-evolution

I know the interaction picture states and operators:
\begin{align}
\lvert\psi_I(t)\rangle &=e^{i\hat{H}_0t}\lvert\psi_S(t)\rangle,\\
\hat{O}_I(t) &=e^{i\hat{H}_0t}\hat{O}_Se^{-i\hat{H}_0t},\\
\hat{H}_I(t)&=e^{i\hat{H}_0t}\hat{H}_\mathrm{int}e^{-i\hat{H}_0t},
\end{align}
but don't understand why we use interaction picture. Is it just used to express Dyson's expansion, $\hat{U}_I(t_2,t_1)=T\{\ e^{-i\int_{t_1}^{t_2}dt\,\hat{H}_I(t)}\}$, in a simple way?

Comment: So what do you see  $H_0$ and $H_I$ representing in physical terms? Have you worked out Feynman Diagrams yet?

Comment: @Countto10 the interaction picture is useful even if you're not doing QFT and not using diagrams. Also bowstring, notice that your equations for $\hat{O}_I$ and $\hat{H}_I$ are the same thing, no need to write both separately.

Comment: The interaction picture is a unification of both Heisenberg and Schrodinger picture in quantum mechanics and its immediate application is in understanding the interaction of a quantum mechanical system (say an atom) with a classical radiation field.

Comment: @DanielSank: Thank you for that, To bowstring:, my book is worked examples based, which was good for fooling myself because the author spends the absolute minimum time on Dyson Series,  just enough to make you feel how lucky we are with Feynman Diagrams, but bad  as it lacks depth, which eventually will catch up with me. +1 I would be interested in the answers. I will list any web references in a little while, I think David Tong - Cambridge-  covers it, both on YouTube lectures and accompanying notes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interaction picture is really just another basis, and as such it is useful because some common calculations are  simplified in this basis.

In particular, when the perturbation is time-dependent, the resulting series can be easier to obtain (i.e. converges faster) because the "main" part (unperturbed) of the dynamics is already accounted for in the definition of basis states $\vert \psi_I(t)\rangle$ in the interaction picture.

Answer (score 2):

I have some conceptual understanding of why using interacting picture. Usually free Hamiltonian or say, some part of Hamiltonian is easy to solve out the solution of wave function or field(in QFT). The interaction picture divides the Hamiltonian into two part: kinetic part $H_0$ (which is easy to solve) and dynamics part $H_I$. The it absorb the kinetic part into wave functions and operators only concern dynamic evolution. The when considering dynamic evolution you don't need to care how its kinetics is. This is pretty important in some cases, like in Quantum field theory calculating the scattering amplitude. It's easier to make perturbative expansions in this picture.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the state vector carries the dynamic (interaction) time dependence while the operator carries the kinetic time dependence not vice versa:"absorb the kinetic part into wave functions and operators only concern dynamic evolution."

Answer (score 0):

Without the interaction picture, you can't use the "**free**" fields expressions to describe a phenomenon of "**interacting**" fields.